# How to create a UDF or View in another database that references the correct sys.objects table in the caller?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, user-defined-functions

Using SQL Server 2008, I'd like to create a UDF that gives me the create date of an object.  This is the code:

```
create function dbo.GetObjCreateDate(@objName sysname) returns datetime as
begin
    declare @result datetime
    select @result = create_date from sys.objects where name = @objname
    return @result
end
go
```

I'd like to put this UDF in the master database or some other shared database so that it is accessible from anywhere, except that if I do that then the `sys.objects` reference pulls from the `master` database instead of the database that I'm initiating my query from.  I know you can do this as the `information_schema` views sit in `master` and just wrap calls to local instances of sys.objects, so I'm hoping there's a simple way to do that with my UDF as well.

Comment: The `information_schema` views are created locally in each database. Also, as a general rule, the Master DB should be left alone. Create a "Utilities" database to hold things like this instead.

Comment: You can see this for yourself. In SSMS, drill down through Databases -> YourDatabase -> Views -> System Views.

Comment: That won't work.  The UDF in Utilities would just access the sys.objects in Utilities instead of the calling database.  Ignore the master part if that's your hangup... I need the sys.objects from the caller, not the db where the UDF is hosted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not do this instead?

1. Create a stored procedure that creates a view in the master database containing all of the information in `sys.objects` from each database on the server.
2. Create a [DDL Trigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175941.aspx) that gets fired whenever a `CREATE`, `ALTER` or `DROP` statement is executed for a database. The trigger would then execute the stored procedure in step #1. This allows the view to be automatically updated.
3. *(Optional)* Create a user defined function that queries the view for the creation date of a given object.

## Stored Procedure DDL:

```
USE [master];
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.BuildAllServerObjectsView
AS

SET NOCOUNT ON;

IF OBJECT_ID('master.dbo.AllServerObjects') IS NOT NULL
    EXEC master..sp_SQLExec 'DROP VIEW dbo.AllServerObjects;';

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..Databases') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #Databases;

DECLARE @CreateView varchar(8000);
SET @CreateView = 'CREATE VIEW dbo.AllServerObjects AS' + CHAR(13)+CHAR(10) + CHAR(13)+CHAR(10);

SELECT name COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS AS 'name'
  INTO #Databases
  FROM sys.databases
 ORDER BY name;

DECLARE @DatabaseName nvarchar(100);
WHILE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #Databases) > 0
BEGIN
    SET @DatabaseName = (SELECT TOP 1 name FROM #Databases ORDER BY name);
    SET @CreateView +='SELECT N'+QUOTENAME(@DatabaseName, '''')+' AS ''database_name''' + CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)
                    + '      ,name COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS AS ''object_name''' + CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)
                    + '      ,object_id' + CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)
                    + '      ,principal_id' + CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)
                    + '      ,schema_id' + CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)
                    + '      ,parent_object_id' + CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)
                    + '      ,type' + CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)
                    + '      ,type_desc' + CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)
                    + '      ,create_date' + CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)
                    + '      ,modify_date' + CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)
                    + '      ,is_ms_shipped' + CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)
                    + '      ,is_published' + CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)
                    + '      ,is_schema_published' + CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)
                    + '  FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@DatabaseName) + '.sys.objects';
    IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #Databases) > 1
        SET @CreateView += CHAR(13)+CHAR(10) + CHAR(13)+CHAR(10) + ' UNION' + CHAR(13)+CHAR(10);
    ELSE
        SET @CreateView += ';';  

    DELETE #Databases
     WHERE name = @DatabaseName;
END;

--PRINT @CreateView --<== Uncomment this to see the DDL for the view.

EXEC master..sp_SQLExec @CreateView;

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..Databases') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #Databases;

GO
```

## Function DDL:

```
USE [master];
GO

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetObjCreateDate(@DatabaseName sysname, @objName sysname) RETURNS DATETIME AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @result datetime;

    SELECT @result = create_date
      FROM master.dbo.AllServerObjects
     WHERE [database_name] = @DatabaseName
       AND [object_name] = @objname;

    RETURN @result;
END
GO
```

## Sample Usage:

```
SELECT master.dbo.GetObjCreateDate('MyDatabase', 'SomeObject') AS 'Created';
SELECT master.dbo.GetObjCreateDate(DB_NAME(), 'spt_monitor') AS 'Created';
```

Comment: That is definitely slick.  The only issue I had is that I have too many databases for the @CreateView variable to hold the whole script, but for what I want to do, that will solve it.  Thank you!

Comment: Great, glad it helped! You should be able to change the `@CreateView` variable from `varchar(8000)` to `nvarchar(max)` if you need additional capacity.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetObjCreateDate(@objName sysname, @dbName sysname) 
RETURNS datetime AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @createDate datetime;
    DECLARE @params nvarchar(50);
    DECLARE @sql nvarchar(500);

    SET @params = '@createDate datetime OUTPUT';

    SELECT @sql = 'SELECT @createDate = create_date FROM ' + @dbName + '.sys.objects WHERE name = ''' + @objname + '''';

    EXEC sp_executesql @sql, @params, @createDate = @createDate OUTPUT;         

     RETURN @createDate
END
;
```

Comment: That won't work as you cannot use dynamic SQL from a function, neither can you call stored procedures.It should be store procedure.

Answer (score 2):

Does it have to be a function? If you just want it accessible everywhere, a trick is to put your code in a varchar and sp_executesql it:

```
create procedure dbo.GetObjCreateDate(@objName sysname) 
as
    declare @sql nvarchar(max)
    select @sql = 'select create_date from sys.objects where name = ''' + @objname + ''''
    EXEC sp_executesql @sql 
go
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I was hoping for an answer specifically for UDFs because I have more uses for this than just the simple case I presented here.  I just picked a simple example to see if I could get help for the greater purpose.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be an undocumented stored procedure that allows you to create your own system objects: `sp_ms_marksystemobject`

You can read more on http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1612

Comment: So close!!!  That seems to work great for stored procs, but not for UDFs.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: that was all I've got.  Sorry :)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [How to Write Your Own System Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa224829%28v=sql.80%29.aspx). I believe that it may help you

Comment: @mattmc3 have you got any success in this? Please, share your results if you are ready :- ]